# Does CNTK C# API support ConvTranspose?

Tags: c#, convolution, cntk

I have a custom dnn model that I have defined and trained in PyTorch that I am trying to deploy in an application written in C# via ONNX.

When I load the model I have the following error:

[image: ONNX -> CNTK import failure]

After some testing, I have found that this only happens when I add the upsampling side of the network (which uses transposed convolution) back in.

The Python API pages [here](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.ops.html#cntk.ops.convolution_transpose) show a `convolution_transpose` function but I cannot find one in the C# API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to update your CNTK, a new version (2.6) is available as of a few days ago, with updates to ONNX described in the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/releasenotes/cntk_2_6_release_notes#operators):

> Major overhaul to ConvolutionTranspose export and import. Attributes such > as output_shape, output_padding, and pads are fully supported.

Comment: Ah should have checked there. Thanks!